# How to change dynamic video resolution during a call (in hangout WebRTC)

Tags: webrtc, resolution, google-hangouts

I'm find hangout's dynamic resolution in google hangout webrtc version.
How to change dynamic video resolution during a call.

[Situation]
- There were three users in room.
- When switching main speaker it is changed same video's resolution (.videoWidth .videoHeight)

I would like to know how it is implemented for many peer connection.﻿

Comment: I'm interested to know if this has been answered for you.

Answer (score 0):

The change your resolution you can use the Hangout Toolstrip at top center of the Hangout interface to change the quality slider from Auto to a lower resolution, but there's a part of me that thinks you might be asking about aspect ratio instead... different devices (webcam, mobile device camera, etc) present in different aspect ratio (16:9 or 4:3). Some webcams allow you to change the aspect ratio, but it's a dependent on the software provided with the camera.

I hope that some part of this was helpful.